# d3: canvas zooming on retina

Tags: d3.js, canvas, zooming, retina

Comparing the Canvas Semantic Zooming example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3681006
with an example adjusted for retina screens (would probably have to view on retina to see it):
https://bl.ocks.org/interwebjill/d7c22e37e7c05ad6018ee62481316737/e0916413c0544dc1251597d0dbb2834cf92c8596

you can see that the zoom center is off. This scale difference creates other problems as well, particularly when using .scaleTime():

https://bl.ocks.org/interwebjill/206425109aa902c2928fa22b8a9f5fd8

Notice that the repartitioning of the x-axis with finer increments is not triggered.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

**UPDATE**
Mike Bostock addressed this issue on the d3 repo here: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/133